# Android MVVM - Where to bind to a Mediaplayer bound service?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I have a permanent bound service with a Mediaplayer and a MediaSession.
I am refactoring my app to an MVVM architecture with HILT .

I'd like to know where I should bind to the service and where to save the IBinder and the media controler :

- The application ?
- the UI fragments or activity?
- the shared viewmodel ?
- the repository ?
- somewhere else ?

The difficulty of using the repository is that it is injected in the viewmodel from a HILT Module.

It would be much appreciated if you  could provide some guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to inject the MediaPlayer into my viewmodel.

First put it into a wrapper class:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import androidx.annotation.RawRes

class SoundPlayer(
    private val context: Context,
) {
    private var mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer().apply {
        setOnPreparedListener { start() }
        setOnCompletionListener { reset() }
    }

    fun reset() = mediaPlayer.reset()

    fun playSound(@RawRes rawResId: Int) {
        val assetFileDescriptor = context.resources.openRawResourceFd(rawResId) ?: return
        mediaPlayer.run {
            reset()
            setDataSource(
                assetFileDescriptor.fileDescriptor,
                assetFileDescriptor.startOffset,
                assetFileDescriptor.declaredLength
            )
            prepareAsync()
        }
    }
}
```

Then inject it using this Module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class SoundPlayerModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideSoundPlayer(@ApplicationContext context: Context) =
        SoundPlayer(context = context)
}
```

then use it in the ViewModel like this, where R.raw.start refers to an MP3 file located at res/raw/start.mp3

```
@HiltViewModel
class ExerciseViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private var soundPlayer: SoundPlayer,
) : ViewModel() {
    ...
    soundPlayer.playSound(R.raw.start)
    ... 
}
```